# Compare hashset with file

Tags: c#, hashset

How can I compare a `hashset` with  the content of a file?

I want some sort of loop that will compare the file contents with the `hashset` and then stop at the place in the `hashset` were it has not found the same contents in the file

Answer (score 1):

Sample

```
string[] array1 = { "cat", "dog", "cat", "leopard", "tiger", "cat" };
var hash = new HashSet<string>(array1);
    string f = "TextFile1.txt";
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
{

    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

    if(!hash.Contains(line))
              break;
    }
}
```